# How to import application properties from iot hub message enrichment into azure data explorer

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-data-explorer

We are using **azure iot hub** and **azure iot edge devices** for multiple of our customers. The devices are sending their telemetry data using **iot hub telemetry messages**. In the iot hub we use **message routing** -> **enrich messages** to add the customer id to the **messages application properties**. This works pretty good if we forward the messages to service bus topics and consume them using azure functions as the application properties are easily accessable there.

Instead of using Azure functions, we now want to store all the telemetry data directly in **azure data explorer databases** and we want to split the messages to one dedicated database per customer (the name of the database is the customer-id).

So far I could not figure out how to access the **application properties** from **iot hub** when importing data to the **data explorer**? I am not even sure that it is possible, but i really hope it is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately automatically routing messages to different databases is not currently supported, please add a request to [Azure Data Explorer user voice](https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice). For now, you can do the message routing to a dedicated event hub per customer (i.e. per database) and [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub) one Azure Data Explorer data connection per database.

Please note that within a data connection you can dynamically route the messages to different tables by adding the table information to the event properties, see sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-hubs-dotnet-ingest/blob/master/EventHubSampleData/EventHub2/Program.cs)

Comment: The tenant information ist not available on the target system and the message enrichment can only add it to the application properties. At the moment we really want to avoid adding another message broker to our system, so the eventhub-solution will not cause happy faces with our architects. We are expecting to receive A LOT of messages so every additional service we add will cost a lot of money.

Comment: Microsoft gives you an option of ingesting data from Iot Hub to Azure Data Explorer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub.Please pay attention to mapping you create. Routing to EventHub after enrichment would be a better choice since Azure Data Explorer can directly ingest in target table as long as schema remains same.

Comment: Direct ingestion from IOT event hub to Azure Data Explorer can only be done within a single database, you can use multiple IOT event hubs (one for each customer) or do the solution proposed above, or do the message routing to storage account and configure Event Grid to Azure Data Explorer, or use the function to write ingest command to the applicable database but again, somewhere in the pipeline you will need to create a data connection/ or ingestion process per DB. From cost perspective the routing to storage account and creating data connection to ADX DB will likely be the cheapest

Comment: @Zainu that mapping does not support application properties.

Comment: @Avnera but i can use one table to import all entries and then use the data from that table (plus a filter) to fill all the other tables. I am aleady using such a mechanism to expand data from an array within the data

Comment: I assume that you refer to update policy, then yes of course this will work for one table per tenant. The original question was regarding sending the events to a dedicated database per tenant and update polices do not work across database boundary.